# Google Chrome Auto Pausing Flash Ads

Tags: google-chrome, flash, jwplayer, ads, vast

Since Google Chrome version 45, flash ads are automatically paused if they are "not important".

When talking about VAST ads played in JWPlayer, how do you determine whether an ad is "important" enough to allow it to autoplay (minimum player size, location,...?)?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that Google Chrome pauses these ads when they are below the fold and 300x250 or below in size, so if you make your player larger and above the fold, you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be min 398x298 as suggest  [this website (nimbb.com)](http://nimbb.com/News/View.aspx?id=473)